# Comparing two elements of a string array with .equals()

Tags: java, arrays, equals

I'm working on a project and I need to compare two elements of the same array

```
private void checkImports()
{
    //import tester
    for(int i = 0; i<theClass.length;i++)
    {   
        for(int j = 0; j<i; j++)
            {
                if(theClass[i].equals(theClass[j]))
                    {
                            System.out.println("There is a double import at line " +i);
                            addError("Double import at line ",i)
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

the array is filled with the following strings:

```
"import java.x;" //0
"import java.y;" //1
"import java.z;" //2
"import java.x;" //3
```

For some reason when I call the equals() method it never evaluates to true when i = 3 and j= 0.
Any explanation as to why the addError method is never called would be much appreciated

Comment: (1) Check for extra spaces in one of your strings (2) Show us the code that fills the array

Comment: @Robert, the OP said these were the array values (I suppose strings). He never said he called some variables/packages like that

Comment: Your code works when tested: [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/w5g8xKvb). Your problem is elsewhere not in the code above, but perhaps with the Strings as `ajb` mentions. Time to use a debugger or to do more intense debugging.

Comment: "import java..." are strings in the array

Comment: The "import java.*" lines don't look like strings.  If those things are somehow strings when your code runs, you should probably describe how that is the case.

Comment: Please show the minimal *executable* code that shows the problem

Comment: okay, i edited the question a bit and made it more clear that those are strings.

Comment: additionally, the code I put here is exactly what I have in eclipse. @ajb has the right solution. There is something wrong with the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible explanations (I mean, there are many explanations, but these two lend themselves for checking first, I think):

1. The comparison with `i==3` and `j==0` is never actually performed (even though you think it is).
2. The values `theClass[0]` and `theClass[3]` are not actually equal (even though you think they are).

You can easily check for both cases, e.g., with the help of a debugger. If you don't like using a debugger, you can also insert a few `System.out.println` statements to check which values the variables `i` and `j` actually assume and that `theClass[0].equals(theClass[3])` actually evaluates to `true`.